# Function returns a undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have something that I don't understand. I try to fetch some data from my database using a mongoose model. Here is the code:

```
function dot(property) {
  const result = Temp.findOne({tempHash: property}).exec( (er,result) =>  result);
}

function verify(req,res,next) {
 console.log(dot(req.query.id), dot(req.query.id));

 if (req.get('host') == dot(req.query.id).host) {
    console.log("Domain is matched. Information is from Authentic email");

    if(req.query.id == dot(req.query.id).tempHash) {
      // ...
```

My `dot` function fetch the values, when I use the `console.log` inside the `exec` callback I have a full object (result).

But when I try to access the object' properties from the `verify` function I have an *undefined*. For example when I want to log the `result.host` or `result.tempHash` I would have my value, not an *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dot` method does not return anything, that's why your result is *undefined*.

Start by making the `dot` method returns the result:

```
async function dot(property) {
  return Temp.findOne({ tempHash: property });
}
```

Now that `dot` returns a `Promise` you just have to call the method and then wait for the result:

```
function verify(req, res, next) {
  dot(req.query.id)
    .then(result => {
      if (!result) return;

      if (req.get('host') === result.host) {
        console.log("Domain is matched. Information is from Authentic email");
        if (req.query.id === result.tempHash) { // this condition is useless
          // ...
        }
      }
    })
    .catch(next);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are working with asynchronous process, mongoose models executes asynchronously, i.e, they return promises that executes later and not instantly. to find more about JavaScript asynchronous programming, you can check out this [MDN async post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

**The following code would do what you are trying to achieve:**.

```
const dot = function(property) {
    return Temp.findOne({tempHash: property}).exec();
};

const verify = async function(req, res, next) {
    //note that result can be null when no match exists in the db
    const result = await dot(req.query.id);
    if (result && req.get('host') == result.host) {
        console.log("Domain is matched. Information is from Authentic email");
    }
};
```